# Есть строка data как определить содержит она "found" или "not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Смысл такой, хочу написать не большой скрип, который будет ходить на удалённый сервер и пинговать большое кол-во устройств, пинговать он будете не через обычный ping, а через запуск скрипта на удалённом сервере, т.е. мой скрип заходит на сервак и запускает blablabla.sh 192.168.1.1, но это не важно. Суть в том, что при выполнении пинга через скрип на сервере, мне не возвращается ошибка, если устройство доступно скрипт отвечает:
`Looking for OpenVPN client with MAC CCCCCCCCCCC... found!`
если устройство не доступно то:
`Looking for OpenVPN client with MAC CCCCCCCCCCC... not found!`
Так вот вопрос заключается в следующем, можно ли как то проверить `print` на его вывод, если там будет found! или not found! То соответственно скрип пишет работает или не работает.
Устройств будет много больше 100 шт.

```
import paramiko
import re
import time

host = 'IP'
user = 'LOGIN'
port = PORT
ssh = 'PATH'

a = 'NAME1'
a1 = 'NAME2'
a2 = 'NAME3'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, port=port, key_filename=ssh)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo ping_sens.sh CCCCCCCCCC')
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
print(data)
```

вывод: `Looking for OpenVPN client with MAC CCCCCCCCCC... found!`

Comment: Да, скрипт [может считывать вывод запущенной им программы](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) или другого скрипта.

Comment: мне нужно считывать print

Comment: Если у вас в программе print(x), вам даже считывать ничего не надо. А если это не у вас в программе - выше уже написано что возможно.

Comment: что конкретно вызывает затруднения? 1- как запустить команду на удалённом сервере в Питоне? (к примеру, через ssh -- fabric/pyinvoke) 2- Как прочитать вывод этой команды? 3- Как вытащить информацию из строк? 4- как ускорить работу для опроса 100 устройств?

Comment: @jfs Как прочитать вывод print что бы в выводе искать слово или found или not found и взаимозависимости от варианта выводить работает или не работает.

Comment: где у вас  print находится?

Comment: @jfs `client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, port=port, key_filename=ssh)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo ping_sens.sh CCCCCCCCCC')
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
print(data)` вывод `Looking for OpenVPN client with MAC CCCCCCCCCC... found!`

Comment: познакомьтесь со [строковыми методами](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). Если этого недостаточно, то с [регулярными выражениями](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)